# Using dplyr to bind rows inside a database

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift

I have two large tables, old_customers and new_customers and I want to row bind them. This is done but either one is too large to load in-memory. However, I'm not sure if `bind_rows` will allow binding of two tables without them being both data frames. I get this error when I try

```
old <- tbl(conn, 'old_customers')
new <- tbl(conn, 'new_customers')
old %>% bind_rows(new)
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a tbl_dbi/tbl_sql/tbl_lazy/tbl
```

The other option would be something like

```
old <- as.data.frame(tbl(conn, 'old_customers'))
new <- as.data.frame(tbl(conn, 'new_customers'))
old %>% bind_rows(new)
```

But again, I am trying to avoid loading this dataset into memory. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The `union` function may be of use here

Comment: @bouncyball, but wouldn't union only return rows in which a key is in both tables? I just want the equivalent of an rbind

Comment: The `union_all` function may be more appropriate then. I apologize with utmost sincerity.

Comment: It looks like that did the trick! @bouncyball. Feel free to submit an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `union_all` function, which operates very similarly to an `rbind` or `bind_rows`, but should have the added advantage of not necessitating the loading of data in memory.

```
old <- tbl(conn, 'old_customers')
new <- tbl(conn, 'new_customers')
old %>% union_all(new)
```